# Chinese character component-based layout engine algorithms

Tags: algorithms, graph-theory, languages

I am looking for a PDF describing Chinese character component-based layout engine algorithms. These should allow for recursive encodings of radical and non-radical components, and the encodings should account for the structural layout of characters based on these layouts.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because is about encoding of the chinese language.